# autohotkey: sometimes button is not clicked

Tags: autohotkey

I wrote such autohotkey script to auto-logon my program:

```
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.
Run info.exe
WinWait, User identification,
Sleep 300
ControlSend, Edit1, user, User identification
ControlSend, Edit2, password, User identification
ControlClick, Button1, User identification
```

The problem is - sometimes `Button1` is not clicked.
When i'm execution script in most cases `Button1` is clicked, but sometimes it doesn't.
When script autoexecuted on locked workstation (this is the scenario I actually need), `Button1` is never clicked.

I've tried to insert `Sleep, 1000` after each line in script but it didn't helped.

The question is why, and how to fix/workaround the problem

I will try today to replace

```
ControlSend, Edit2, password, User identification
ControlClick, Button1, User identification
```

with

```
ControlSend, Edit2, password{Enter}, User identification
```

probably this will work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I spent a week tring to solve my problem anf finally resolved it. Hope this will help to someone.

Never try to send **CAPITALIZED** letter to autohotkey, instead send `shiftdown` and `shiftup`

**Wrong:**

`ControlSend, Edit2, passworD, User identification`

**Right:**

`ControlSend, Edit2, passwor{SHIFTDOWN}d{SHIFTUP}, User identification`

Also it would be better to avoid `ControlClick` if possible. To click a button `ControlSend` a `Space` to it.

Comment: Ah!  I wish I would have seen your post earlier.  `ControlSend` is case-sensitive - which you have unwittingly discovered.